# Asbestos exposure concerns of could considerable exposure be a contributing factor to exacerbating existing chronic skin condition with ill health?

Tags: sealing

Asbestos exposure concerns of could considerable exposure be a contributing factor to exacerbating existing chronic skin condition with ill health?
I have lived in existing rented property for approximately 16 years unbeknownst to me asbestos containing materials existed throughout, I was badly flooded by the landlords in July 2019 resulting in significant damaged living room ceilings/hallway walls&ceilings the ACM. All light fighting and fixtures were removed exposing holes left not covered or sealed I have been left to live within the property. The materials needing removed them becoming more damaged as landlords allowed a company to change all existing Windows and doors cracking materials further whilst doing so as well as disturbing major areas to hallway ceiling and walls without any safety measures in place as I was in property when work took place the landlords claim no harm or risks posed to my health by having been exposed to asbestos during works combined with living in below standards expected for dwellings?
Can anyone advice me if everything combined 'could have been or be' of any harm to conditions in the last 24 months, Particularly more so the last 12?
I also returned after a 24 stay away as instructed during removals, When I returned brickwork around new plasterboard for ceilings was not sealed with any poly coverings.
I suspect bedroom doors not sealed off, Varied furnishings, Beddings, Floors and clothing etc have not been properly protected from fibres becoming airborne. Is it a good idea to replace everything to be safe?

Comment: You need to seek local legal & medical advice. Your health is not something we can diagnose for you. Your legal recourse is also dependent on territory & local laws.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently in the process of legal and medical matters relating however it is so frustrating that the landlord is adamant the are in no way at fault however I have photographs of exposed unsealed areas of works done during removals which I wonder should I consider replacing flooring and furnishings due to skin irritations heightening?

Comment: This is in dire need if editing as it is so confusing.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that there has been any asbestos exposure? Where in the world are you located? When was the building constructed?

Comment: Containment procedures _during_ removal would include sealing areas off with heavy plastic film and a series of decontamination stages for exit from the sealed area. However, none of that should remain after the asbestos was all removed - there's no further need for it. At least, I _think_ that's what you're asking about there towards the end...

Answer (score 1):

There are four parts to asbestos abatement: 1) discovery and testing, 2) removal, 3) containment during removal, and 4) certification that all has been removed and the air is clean.

1. Suspected asbestos is sampled and put in a “chain of custody” and sent to a “certified” testing agency. If the sample exceeds limits set by the government (DEQ), then it must be removed or covered if it can be disturbed.
2. Methods of removal is established by DEQ. Included in those regulations is containment.
3. Containment is to keep the asbestos particles from flying around so it doesn’t contaminate other environments. Usually this is done by sealing the build (or area of work) and installing a fan that creates a negative air flow. That is to say, air from the containment area should not be released into other environments.
4. During and after the abatement process air samples are taken by certified technicians. At the end of the process, the abatement company gives a certification that ALL the asbestos has been removed and the area is clear and safe to be in.

I would check to see if they are certified by DEQ. If not, I’d get an attorney. I’d also notify the local Building Department and Builders Board. You should be able to get a copy of all the certifications.

I’ve never heard of asbestos causing a skin reaction. It’s usually associated with lung cancer. However, we are all different and you should be tested.